# Hide the content based on Children class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need one help with the code, I have two HTML div blocks with the same class name and there is one extra h2 tag with different class present in one div block. I want to hide if h2 class name is not present in that div and show if the h2 class name is present. Please find the below mentioned code that I have created.

-- First block Div --

```
<div class="course-content">
    <h2 class="accesshide"></h2>
    <ul class="topics">
        <li class="data-list">Content not to Display</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Content to Display</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

-- Second block Div --

```
<div class="course-content">
    <ul class="topics">
        <li class="data-list">Content not to Display</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="single-section">
        <p>Content to Display</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

-- jQuery Code --

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".course-content").find(".accesshide")) {
        $(".course-content").find(".topics").show();
    } else if ($(".course-content").find(".single-section")) {
        $(".course-content").find(".topics").hide();
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="course-content">
        <h2 class="accesshide"></h2>
        <ul class="topics">
            <li class="data-list">Content not to Display</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="row">
            <p>Content to Display (this statement is inaccurate)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="course-content">
        <ul class="topics">
            <li class="data-list">Content not to Display (this statement is inaccurate)</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="single-section">
            <p>Content to Display</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please use hasClass() function to check if H2 has the desired class

Comment: You probably want to change the text in the `topics` items as they seem to not match the logic you're asking for.

Comment: What do you need if there is a `.single-section` in the block - hide or show the `.topics` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the controls are independent events, they should be evaluated separately. Therefore, two separate `if` blocks should be used. In the second event in the solution below, the first child element of the parent element of the selected element is hidden by selecting it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($(".course-content").find(".accesshide")) {
      $(".course-content > .accesshide").find(".topics").show();
  } 

  // Because both <div> elements have the ".topics" class style applied, the ".single-section" 
  // element is selected and the first child element of the parent element is hidden.
  if ($(".course-content").find(".single-section")) {
      $(".course-content > .single-section").parent().children(':first-child').hide();
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="course-content">
  <h2 class="accesshide"></h2>
  
  <ul class="topics">
      <li class="data-list">Content not to Display</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="row">
      <p>Content to Display</p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
    
<div class="course-content">
  <ul class="topics">
      <li class="data-list">Content not to Display</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="single-section">
      <p>Content to Display</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution Sercan, actually this code worked as expected. Thanks a bunch

Comment: 1) If the page hasn't reqired blocks, jQuery objects will represents the empty set of DOM elements, so you don't need to wrap your code in the `if` statements. 2) The [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) methods `get the *descendants* of each element in the current set of matched elements`, so the first part of your code doesn't work. The block is visible because it's visible by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial using a CSS child selector (`>`).  Just find the collection of elements that are an `accesshide` child of a `course-content` and hide the `topics` child of their parents.

You could do something similar with a descendant selector ( ), but since you know it's a child for this case, the child selector is perhaps more accurate.

[MDN's Child Combinator docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.course-content>.accesshide').parent().find('.topics').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="course-content">
        <h2 class="accesshide"></h2>
        <ul class="topics">
            <li class="data-list">Content not to Display</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="row">
            <p>Content to Display</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="course-content">
        <ul class="topics">
            <li class="data-list">Content not to Display (this should actually be shown - there's no h2 in the parent div)</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="single-section">
            <p>Content to Display</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Tibrogargan, I wanted to hide the second div block when h2 classname is not present. I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hide if h2 class name is not present in that div and show if the h2 class name is present.

You don't need any JS code, just only CSS with [adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) or [general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) sibling combinator. For example:

```css
.course-content .topics {
  display: none;
}
.course-content .accesshide + .topics {
  display: block;
}
```

When you have to use jQuery then you can use the same logic and the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method (or [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/)):

```js
$(".course-content").find(".topics").hide();
$(".course-content").find(".accesshide").next(".topics").show();
```

If the controlled block can be both before and after the control block, the shortest way is to use the [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method. If you need to show the `.topics` block if there is an `.accesshide` block or a `.single-section` block nearby, you can use this jQuery method for both cases:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".course-content").find(".topics").hide();
    $(".course-content").find(".accesshide, .single-section").siblings(".topics").show();
});
```

```html
<div class="course-content">
    <ul class="topics">
        <li class="data-list">Content not to Display</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <p>There are no special blocks nearby</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="course-content">
    <h2 class="accesshide"></h2>
    <ul class="topics">
        <li class="data-list">Show because of the .accesshide block</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Case 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="course-content">
    <ul class="topics">
        <li class="data-list">Show because of the .single-section block</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="single-section">
        <p>Case 2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Gleb Kemsarsky. Actually I wanted to hide the div blocks using jQuery.

Comment: I've added a short jQuery version for both cases from your answer.

Comment: Now the content present with the classname-"data-list" is hidden in two blocks, but I wanted to hide only if classname-"accesshide" is not present then classname-"data-list" should be hidden.

Comment: I've updated the answer just now

Comment: If we provide content for the class name "accesshide" then the content will still display right.

Comment: So you need to show the `.topics` block only if the `.accesshide` block exists and empty. Have I understood right?

Comment: Not exactly, Initially everything will shown, hide the second div classname content i.e  topics only if the classname - accesshide is not present within the main div class i.e course-content.

Comment: Ok. One more question: is `.single-section` important too? Do you need hide or show the `.topics` block because of `.single-section`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241984/discussion-between-shas-and-gleb-kemarsky).